# Why json_extract works but json_extract_scalar does not?

Tags: sql, json, select, presto

I have a dataset containing a column in json with an attribute giving me a list, and I would like to unnest it to join some different data.

I thought about `json_extract_scalar` the json_data, then I could `split` it and finally `unnest` with other operations, however I got a problem.

In my case, when i run the `json_extract` it works fine but i cannot convert to a varchar. In the other hand, if i use `json_extract_scalar` it returns a null value.

I think the problem should be the quotation marks, but I am not sure how to deal with it - and even if this is the correct problem.

Let me give you a sample of the data:

```
{"my_test_list":["756596263-0","743349523-371296","756112380-0","755061590-0"]}
```

Can you guys give me some advice?

I'm querying SQL in Presto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are storing under key `my_test_list` is a JSON array, not a scalar value - which is why [`json_extract_scalar()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar) returns `null`.

It is rather unclear how you want to use that data. A typical solution is to `cast` it to an `array`, that you can then use as needed, for example by unnesting it. The base syntax would be:

```
cast(json_extract(mycol, '$.my_test_list') as array(varchar))
```

You would then use that in a lateral join, like:

```
select t.mycol, x.myval
from mytable t
cross join unnest(
    cast(json_extract(mycol, '$.my_test_list') as array(varchar))
) as x(myval)
```

Comment: GMB, each line in my dataset has a row with a list like this one. My idea is to count each element in the list. So the Item "A" can appear in several lists across the rows and I would like to count it. I am not sure I am making myself clear as I would like, however I appreciate your help anyway

Comment: @DanielMiranda: so: `select x.myval, count(*) cnt from mytable t cross join unnest(
    cast(json_extract(mycol, '$.my_test_list') as array<varchar>) ) as x(myval) group by x.myval`

Comment: Perfect! It worked fine and I could do the operation! Thanks, GMB!